# Function for formatting an array

Tags: javascript

This function is working fine but I'm looking for any better alternative:

```
function formate(array) {
    var formattedArray = [];
    var count = array.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        formattedArray.push({
            all: array[i].all ? array[i].all.split(',') : [],
            any: array[i].any ? array[i].any.split(',') : [],
            not: array[i].not ? array[i].not.split(',') : [],
        });
    }

    return formattedArray;  
}
```

Input:

```
[{all: "one,two", any: "three,four", not: ""},{all: "five,six", any: "", not: "seven"}]
```

Output:

```
[{all: ["one", "two"], any: ["three", "four"], not: []}, {all: ["five", "six"], any: [], not: ["seven"]}]
```

Comment: I am not sure how it is not efficient? Do you see performance problems? You could switch to map but running jsperf tests might determine if it is better or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formate = array => array.map(({all, any, not}) => ({all: all.split(","), any: any.split(","), not: not.split(",")}));
```

With empty arrays:

```
const formate = array => array.map(({all, any, not}) => ({all: all?all.split(","):[], any: any?any.split(","):[], not: not?not.split(","):[]}));
```

Comment: I need to avoid that empty string but  your code producing something like this '[{all: ["one", "two"], any: ["three", "four"], not: [""]}, {all: ["five", "six"], any: [""], not: ["seven"]}]'

Comment: How to do that with the above code. Can you help me?

Comment: @arjun shure, just include the ternary you used.